# Selected UICollectionViewCell not highlighting Image when view reappears on certain cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, viewwillappear

I have a simple app with a `Tab Bar Controller` where the first `tab` is a `UITableViewController` (Timeline) and the second `tab` is also a `UITableViewController` (Settings).

Within Settings, the user can click on the "Themes" `cell` and be taken to a `UICollectionView` with 3 cells on each row and 4 rows.

The `cells` contain images and labels populated by `NSArrays` in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UICollectionView`.

I have a custom image that appears (on top of the cell) when I select a cell and I've noticed that on some occasions, if I select a cell and go to the other tab (Timeline) and back again, the custom image for the selected cell doesn't reappear.

However, if I select a cell and then go back to the Settings by popping the segue (push) and then back into the UICollectionView, the tick appears.

To clarify: The Steps are:

1) Select a Theme

2) Custom image (tick) appears on that cell

3) Go back to the Timeline (without going back to the Settings)

4) Go back to the second tab and the UICollectionView is still loaded

5) Tick is not there*

*This only occurs with about 8 of the 12 images but saying that, 4 of them are working which is what confuses me.

Here's the code in the `cellForItem`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ThemeCell *ThemeCell = (ThemeCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Theme Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellData = [self.themeLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 1, 2)];
    dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick.png"];
    themeCell.cellLabel.text = cellData;
    themeCell.cellImages.image = self.themeImages[indexPath.row];

    self.selectedThemeString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Selection"];

    NSLog(@"Selected Theme String = %@", self.selectedThemeString);

    if (!self.selectedThemeString)
    {        
        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        themeCell.backgroundView = dot;
        [themeCell addSubview:dot];
    }

    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"Loaded");
        themeCell.backgroundView = self.checkmark;
        [themeCell addSubview:self.checkmark];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Loaded");
        themeCell.backgroundView = nil;
    }
return themeCell;
```

Here's some custom code I put in the `viewWillAppear`:

```
    self.selectedThemeString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Selection"];

    if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Original"])
    {
        NSLog(@"1...");
        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Peacock"])
    {
        NSLog(@"2...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Mystical"])
    {
        NSLog(@"3...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Zebra"])
    {
        NSLog(@"4...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Simplicity"])
    {
        NSLog(@"5...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Rainbow"])
    {
        NSLog(@"6...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Prosperity"])
    {
        NSLog(@"7...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Leopard"])
    {
        NSLog(@"8...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Hypnotic"])
    {
        NSLog(@"9...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:8 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Dunes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"10...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Twirl"])
    {
        NSLog(@"11...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedThemeString isEqualToString:@"Oceanic"])
    {
        NSLog(@"12...");

        self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:11 inSection:0];
    }


    [self.cView reloadData];
}
```

So I can tell you that for example, "Zebra" is one of the affected cells, which appears as the 1st cell on the second row (which I assume is indexPathforRow:4 and inSection:0 because there are no sections.

However, Simplicity works when I go back to the timeline and back to the UICollectionView.

Any guidance on this weird bug would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. My mistake for not using the property to set the image and instead creating a new image with the same functionality in the cellForItem. Issue fixed.